# Finish removing the [untagged] tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Earlier I'd flagged a question that was tagged [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), which has been fixed. However, there are still questions tagged as such... I'm reasonably certain that this is not a tag we'd want to encourage. Could these be re-tagged and the [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag blacklisted?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged

Comment: a sub-category of "not otherwise specified", an entry in a properties list "no know properties".

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing those to our attention. I've fixed all [but one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17809/that-that-correct-in-writing) (which can only be fixed by a mod, it seems).

I believe [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is a system tag, so it can't be removed completely. One use is when a migrated question is tagged with tags that we don't have here.

Answer (score 2):

> Could these be re-tagged and the [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag blacklisted?

[untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) cannot be black-listed because it is the tag that is automatically added to a question when a tag is removed, and that tag is the only one used from the question. This happens because a tag that is used from just a question is deleted after 30, or 60 days.  [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is also used when a moderator of another site migrates a question on EL&U, and that question doesn't use any tag used on EL&U; as the tags that don't exist in the site where the question is being migrated are deleted, [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) replaces those tags, when the question ends with no tags. (A question always needs to have at least a tag.)

Instead of flagging the question, you could have found a pertinent tag for that question, and suggested an edit. As far as I remember, suggesting an edit to add a tag, or replace a tag is allowed.